# Why different hex editors show different binary for a file?

Tags: windows, file-format, hex-editor, hexdump

When I open a binary(in this case it is `C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe`), different hex editors show different result each other, for the one same file. I tested it on starting point of section headers, so notice the starting address of `2E 74 65 78 74 00 00 00` (`".text..."`).

- [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) :
  [image] — Starts at **`00000200`**.
- [UltraEdit](https://www.ultraedit.com/) :
  [image: hex image 2] — Starts at **`00000200`**.
- [PEview](http://wjradburn.com/software/) :
  [image] — Starts at **`000001E8`**.
- [Frhed](http://frhed.sourceforge.net/en/) :
  [image] — Starts at **`000001E8`**.

Comment: I suggest to read [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable#Technical_details)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are different files.

From [*When is System32 not System32?*](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mrsnrub/2011/11/22/q-when-is-system32-not-system32/) [emphasis mine]:

> In 32-bit Windows there is just one `System32` folder which contains many native binaries (or hard links), and there is no way to execute 64-bit code on 32-bit Windows.
>
> With 64-bit Windows, however, we have "Windows On Windows 64" (WOW64) which allows 32-bit processes to run through a wrapper, and there are some things to take into account in this scenario:
>
> 1. Only 32-bit DLLs can be loaded into 32-bit processes, and only 64-bit DLLs can be loaded into 64-bit processes.
>    […]
> 2. 32-bit processes expect to work seamlessly on 64-bit Windows, so because of (1) we need to have both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of some binaries.
>    […]
> 3. In order to facilitate (2) but not break native (x64) processes' behaviour, 32-bit processes get certain I/O redirected without their knowledge.
>    […]
>
> […]
>
> For 32-bit processes running on x64 Windows:
> **- `%systemroot%\System32` is redirected to `%systemroot%\SysWOW64`**
> […]

My guess is some hex editors are 32-bit and get redirected to `SysWOW64`, some are 64-bit and see the "real" `System32`. Different editors perceive different `System32`, hence different `notepad.exe`.

If you copy `notepad.exe` to a folder that is not affected and analyze the copy then all editors will show the same content. Which file will you see? This depends whether the copying tool is 32-bit or 64-bit.

Comment: I didn't run the binary(notepad.exe). I just opened it through hex editor.

Comment: You are right. They may consider the file path differently. When I move the binary from `System32` to `Desktop`, they show the same result :)

Comment: @jinbeomhong Good idea! I assimilated it into my answer, thanks. But don't forget to move the file back (if you really meant "move"; "copy" is safer).

Comment: Thanks! My system is 64 bit Windows. So when i right-click a file in System32 and copy it and right click in Desktop and paste it, the copying tool would be acting as 64 bit process. So the System32 is real System32(64bit file).

Comment: Update : Whether i copy a file in GUI on x86 or x64 system seems to be unrelated to copying behavior. When i copy a file in `System32` to `Desktop`, the copied file is actually 64bit file. When i copy a file in `SysWOW64` to `Desktop`, the coped file is actually 32bit file. Of course, third party copying tool would show the different behavior.

Comment: When a 32 bit process tries to access anything in system32 it will be silently redirected to syswow64 and get the 32 bit version of the file. A 64 bit process would access the 64 bit file in system32.