# nano on windows confuses folders

Tags: windows, powershell, nano

Powershell got opened in this folder

```
C:/Windows/system32
```

Then, I entered this command, then typed the content and saved the file:

```
nano C:/windows/system32/goeclipse.bat
```

And the file gets saved as:

```
c:/Windows/SysWOW64/goeclipse.bat
```

And then again I do the original command, and nano shows the file content - which means nano thinks the file is in `C:/Windows/system32/goeclipse.bat`

Whereas, the file is surely in `C:/Windows/SysWOW64/goeclipse.bat`

Why does nano think that Windows/SysWOW64 is Windows/system32

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why different hex editors show different binary for a file?](https://superuser.com/questions/1481983/why-different-hex-editors-show-different-binary-for-a-file)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I said nano thinks file is in a different folder.

Comment: That question title is very misleading... However, the answer seems very relevant.